# Building custom cigar box - is there a MAYA or 3DSM to wooden cutout service

Tags: wood, woodworking, prefab

I am looking to build a custom cigar box, and was wondering if I were to design it in MAYA or 3D Studio Max and the figure out all the different pieces I would need. Is there a metal, plastic, or wooden production service that would send me the cutouts in the mail?

Answer (score 2):

Besides Shapeways, check out [Ponoko](http://www.ponoko.com/), [Big Blue Saw](http://www.bigbluesaw.com/), and [100kGarages](http://www.100kgarages.com/).

- Shapeways does 3D printing of plastics & metals.
- Ponoko can do laser cutting of wood/plastic/fabric/rubber as well as 3D printing.
- Big Blue Saw does laser or water jet cutting of wood/plastic/metal.
- 100kGarages is more of a community of workshops with digital fabrication tools.

Answer (score 1):

For plastic and metal, yes. Look into [Shapeways](http://shapeways.com), which will let you upload models and print them out. I haven't used it yet but they get very good press.